# Get the matched column name

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I get the name of the matched column? (eg name/type/country/city)

My table is:

```
USER
ID int
NAME varchar
TYPE varchar
COUNTRY varchar
CITY varchar
```

My sql:

```
SELECT *
FROM USER 
WHERE NAME LIKE '%".$search."%' 
    OR TYPE LIKE '%".$search."%' 
    OR COUNTRY LIKE '%".$search."%' 
    OR CITY LIKE '%".$search."%'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT *
,   COALESCE(
    CASE WHEN NAME LIKE '%".$search."%' THEN 'name' END
,   CASE WHEN NAME TYPE '%".$search."%' THEN 'type' END
,   CASE WHEN COUNTRY LIKE '%".$search."%' THEN 'country' END
,   CASE WHEN CITY LIKE '%".$search."%' THEN 'city' END
) as matched
FROM USER
WHERE NAME LIKE '%".$search."%'
   OR TYPE LIKE '%".$search."%'
   OR COUNTRY LIKE '%".$search."%'
   OR CITY LIKE '%".$search."%'
```

When a single row matches on multiple columns, `matched` will return one name that corresponds to the first column that matched in the order `{name, type, country, city}`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, viz to expand the `OR` into a `UNION` specifying explicitly which column matches:

```
SELECT ..., GROUP_CONCAT(Match) as Match
FROM
(
    SELECT ..., 'Name' as Match
    FROM USER WHERE 
    NAME LIKE '%".$search."%' 

    UNION

    SELECT ..., 'Type' as Match
    FROM USER WHERE 
    TYPE LIKE '%".$search."%' 

    UNION

    SELECT ..., 'Country' as Match
    FROM USER WHERE 
    COUNTRY LIKE '%".$search."%' 

    UNION

    SELECT ..., 'City' as Match
    FROM USER WHERE 
    CITY LIKE '%".$search."%'
) x
GROUP BY ...
```

As per Frazz's comment, the wrapper grouping is needed to eliminate the duplicates created by the `Match` column, which will otherwise prevent the default distinct behaviour of `UNION`.

Comment: This way you might get duplicate rows if the same row matches on more than one column. I'm not sure that is what the OP wants.